# ask Reduction of Order for Linear 2nd-Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is best to describe the procedure with a concrete example. Consider the

$$y''(t)+6y'(t)+9y(t)=0$$

We know that a solution to this problem is $y_1=e^{-3t}$. To obtain the
general solution we need a second linearly independent solution to the
problem.

We find the second solution by assuming $y_2(t)=v(t)e^{-3t}$ where v(t) is an unknown function.

My question: how do we know $y_2(t)$ and $y_1(t)$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent if and only if there is no real number $R$ such that $y_1=Ry_2$. If $y_2(t)=v(t)y_1(t)2$, then if $v$ is not a constant function, then obviously there is no single real number $R$ such that $y_2=Rvy_1$. Hence they are linearly independent.

But also, this confusion can be avoided altogether if we approach this differently. Notice that $y''+6y'+9=y''+3y'+3y'+9=(y'+3y)'+3(y'+3y)$. Let $z=y'+3y$. Thus $z'+3z'=0$. The general solution of this equation is easily provable to be $z(t)=A\exp(-3t)$. Hence $y'(t)+3y(t)=A\exp(-3t)$. We have reduced the order of the second-order equation to first order. This can be solved using the integrating factor. We have $\exp(3t)y'(t)+3\exp(3t)y(t)=A=[\exp(3t)y(t)]'$, hence $\exp(3t)y(t)=At+B$. This implies $y(t)=(At+B)\exp(-3t)=At\exp(-3t)+B\exp(-3t)$. Once you know this, the linear independence of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is trivial.